# Update hostname for Mysql user using Ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-module

I want to update my MYSQL user using ansible-playbook.

**What I tried:**
I checked out the MySQL module doc but there is no option to update the hostname of a user.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_user_module.html#parameter-host_all

**Expected result:**
User updated with the new hostname.

**Current Ansible PlayBook:**
I want to update *user1*'s hostname

```
  - name: Create database user with name 'app' and password with all database privileges for host patientApp-02
    mysql_user:
      login_user: root
      login_password: ellora
      name: user1
      password: user1password
      host: hostname
      priv: '*.*:ALL'
      state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

there is `host` option in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: I can not update with this 'host' option, there is no option to update the host. It will be helpful if you share the playbook to update hostname for a particular user

Comment: can you send me the playbook which you are using right now?